# Delay in starting the docker container - More than 10 bind mounts

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-volume

I am trying to run a perl script inside the container. The script will be accessing more than 10 servers for read and write purposes. The servers are present both in local and other countries. So while running the docker image, i am bind mounting all the volumes. This in turn causes huge delay in starting the container.

Is there any optimal way to handle this scenario ? Is it possible to pre-mount those volumes before starting the container (like mounting during docker build) ?

Comment: You might run multiple containers that each only dealt with a single remote server, with a message bus like RabbitMQ to coordinate activity; or you can mount the servers directly on the host instead of having Docker manage that.

Answer (score 0):

During docker build you can't mount anything because you essentially building image which can be ran anywhere - on any docker/kubernetes cluster.
so mount make sense only during run command.

you can try creating nfs (or just local volume) volume in advance and mount it by name during run. it may be faster just because volume is already created. here is a doc:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_create/
search for `--opt type=nfs`
and here is how to use created volume:
https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#start-a-container-with-a-volume